# Is it okay to use attributes from a tag in another tag?

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to know if it is a problem to use an attribute of a tag in another tag, which does not have this attribute.

For example: in the `<video>` attribute we have `src`.
If I put `<p src="...">` will there be any problem? I know it's wrong, but it's just a question!

I ask this because I can capture the src attribute inside P using javascript. Example:

```js
var tag = document.getElementsByTagName("p") 
for (var i = 0; i < tag.length; i++) {
    alert(tag.item(i).getAttribute("src"))
}
```

```html
<p src="...">Hello!</p>
```

I would like to know if there is any limitation for this, or if there will be any incompatibility.

Thanks.

Comment: image all the tags as a function. src has a defined prop in video, but in p is not. you can still pass  it down, but it not doing anything

Comment: “*I ask this because I can capture the `src` attribute inside P using JavaScript*” - what are you trying to do that involves retrieving non-standard attributes from elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an attribute with `data-` prefix for that purpose.

> Custom data attributes are intended to store custom data, state, annotations, and similar, private to the page or application, for which there are no more appropriate attributes or elements.

source: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#custom-data-attribute

So, in your case it could be something like that:

```js
var tag = document.getElementsByTagName("p") 
for (var i = 0; i < tag.length; i++) {
    alert(tag.item(i).getAttribute("data-src"))
}
```

```html
<p data-src="...">Hello!</p>
```

If you don't do that, you may face compatibility issues in the future.

Answer (score 2):

No limits. In fact in HTML5 spec you can define your own custom nodes.

Indeed adding additional attributes to exiting element (such as a `p`) will yield best-practice warnings.

https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#elements-in-the-dom

However there is a convenient place for custom attributes within the `data-*` attributes:

```html
<p data-src='//custom/path.png'></p>
```

Then you have the added bonus of the js `dataset`:

```js
let $node = $('p')
$node.dataset.src == '//custom/path.png'
```

https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes

But also you can also invent your own nodes:

```
<mycustomnode></mycustomnode>
```

Aside from that - go nuts!

Answer (score 2):

Better avoid using attributes that are not part of the tag. Use the data attributes for that:

```js
const tag = document.querySelector('p');
console.log({
  foo: tag.dataset.foo,
  moo: tag.dataset.moo
});
```

```html
<p data-foo="bar" data-moo="goo">Hello dataset</b>
```

Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes